# Show that the positive units of $K$ form a group isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a cubic field such that $r_1=r_2=1$. Suppose $K$ is imbedded in $ \mathbb R$

($r_1$ and $r_2$ are the usual notations, $r_1$ denotes the number of isomorphisms $\sigma : K \to \mathbb R$ and $r_1+2r_2=n$, where $n$ is the degree of $K$).

I would like to know how to approach the following question:

Show that the positive units of $K$ form a group isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ and that every positive unit of $K$ is of norm $1$.